# parse a website with beautiful soup - attempting to parse value unsuccessfully

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Hi everyone i am parsing an html doc with beautifulsoup. However, one area of information I cant seem to parse:

the html:

```
<small>
<span class="label label-primary">CVE-2019-11198</span>
<span class="label label-warning">6.1 - Medium</span>
- August 05, 2019
</small>
```

I am parsing this whole block, but want to parse the `CVE-2019-11198` , `6.1` , `Medium` , and `August 05, 2019` as separate values. Instead im getting the whole block under `<small>` with the following code:

original:

```
cves=soup.find_all("div", class_="cve_listing")
for cve in cves:
    #CVE, vuln numeric rating, vuln sev cat, vuln date
    vulninfo=cve.find("small").text
```

updated:

```
cves=soup.find_all("div", class_="cve_listing")
for cve in cves:
    vulncve=cve.find("span", class_="label-primary")
    vulninfo=cve.select_one('span.label').parent
    vulninfores=[x.get_text(strip=True) for x in vulninfo.contents if len(x.text) > 1]
```

outputs:

```
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'
```

any thoughts on how to parse this efficiently?

Comment: Use the `<span>` classes to get their text, then remove them from `vulinfo` and parse what's left?

Comment: @MattDMo - the problem is doing that its not parsing anything. For example:  `vulncve=cve.find("span", class_="label label-primary").text`

Comment: Can you give us the URL you're trying to parse? Alternatively, is there an API you can use or an RSS feed you can parse, something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bit modify your question.

1. You have selected `"div", class_="cve_listing"` but didn't show the html
2. You can't invoke get_text() and contents method at the same time. Try the below code:

**Example:**

```
cves=soup.find_all("div", class_="cve_listing")
for cve in cves:
    vulncve=cve.find("span", class_="label-primary")
    vulninfo=cve.select_one('span.label')
    vulninfores=[x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.select(".cve_listing small")][-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not having the url of the actual page means I cannot test it, but supposing the html is correct and you can reach it as stated in your question, this is one way of getting that info:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<small>
<span class="label label-primary">CVE-2019-11198</span>
<span class="label label-warning">6.1 - Medium</span>
- August 05, 2019
</small>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
data = soup.select_one('span.label').parent
desired_result = [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in data.contents if len(x.text) > 1]
print(desired_result)
```

Result:

```
['CVE-2019-11198', '6.1 - Medium', '- August 05, 2019']
```

BeautifulSoup documentation: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Thanks for this, but im looking to parse the result into separate results - e.g. result1=cve-2019-111986.1, result2=medium, etc

Comment: Give me a moment @Jshee...

Comment: @Jshee now you have a list with 3 (separate) items. Is this what you are after? Also, let me know if you need a dictionary (and if you are comfortable with transforming a list into a dict) -- or a dataframe

Comment: Hi @platipus_on_fire - please see updated code and the error I'm getting

Comment: @Jshee the code works. Try and update your packages, do `pip install -U bs4`, it should sort out your issue.